# How to find a vector potential (inverse curl)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If you are given a vector field, how do you find a vector potential for it?

In my *particular* case, I need to find a vector field $\vec{A}$ such that

$$
\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{A}(\,\vec{r}) = \begin{cases} B_0\hat{z} && \text{if $\vec{r} \in$ some cylinder along } \hat{z} \newline \vec{0} && \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}
$$

**but** I'm hoping for a better answer than "guess-and-check" (or at least, a more generic way of guess-and-checking) that would help me in other cases as well.

#### Note:

The vector field (and hence, the potential) does not necessarily go to zero as we approach infinity.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81405/anti-curl-operator

Comment: @WillJagy: Looking at it, thanks. (Not sure if it works yet or not.)

Comment: It looks like the question is a duplicate of the question in Will's comment.

Comment: @Fabian, Will: I got $\vec{A} = \langle -y, x \rangle$, which is true for inside the cylinder, but which cannot be true outside. However, if $\vec{A}$ is continuous (which it must be because of my problem, since it's a magnetic vector potential), that means it must have nonzero curl outside, right? So how does that work?

Comment: @Will, Fabian: Here's a [link to my calculation at the boundary](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=curl%5B%7B-+y+%2F+2+%2F+sqrt%28x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2%29%2C+x+%2F+2+%2F+sqrt%28x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2%29%2C+0%7D%5D).

Comment: @Merhad: so in fact you are most interested in the particular case (then of course it is not duplicate).

Comment: @Fabian: Not really; I actually found the solution for this one by dumb luck -- I forgot to put the square root sign. Yet I still don't know how to solve something like this without guess-and-checking, so I'd like to know how to go about doing that.

Comment: @Merhad: it is explained in the answer to the question linked by Will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already noted in an [old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81405/anti-curl-operator), the inverse of the curl operator (up to possible problems with the domain not having a star shape) can be written as
$$\vec A(\vec r)= \int_0^1 [\vec B(t \vec r) \times (t\vec r) ]\, dt.$$

For concreteness, let us assume that the cylinder has radius $R$ and we use cylindrical coordinates $\vec r=(\rho \cos\theta,\rho \sin \theta, z)$. Then we have
$$A_x(\vec r)= -y B_0 \int_0^1 t \mathop H(R-t\rho)\,dt$$
with $H$ the [Heaviside-step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). Similarly,
$$A_y(\vec r)= x B_0 \int_0^1 t \mathop H(R-t\rho)\,dt$$ and $$A_z(\vec r)=0.$$

To find an explicit form of $\vec A(\vec r)$, we need to perform the integral ($\rho= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$)
$$\int_0^1 t \mathop H(R-t\rho)\,dt = \int_0^{\mathop{\rm min}(R/\rho,1)}\!\!\!t\,dt = \tfrac12\mathop{\rm min}(R/\rho,1)^2 .$$

*Edit:*
Putting everything together, we have
$$\vec{A}(\vec r) = \tfrac12 B_0\mathop{\rm min}(R/\rho,1)^2 \begin{pmatrix}-y\\x\\0\end{pmatrix}
=\tfrac12 B_0\mathop{\rm min}\left[\frac{R^2}{x^2+y^2},1\right] \begin{pmatrix}-y\\x\\0\end{pmatrix}. $$

Comment: I'm confused with your notation... isn't the answer supposed to be a vector?

Comment: How about $\vec{A}(\vec r) = (A_x, A_y, A_z)$?

Comment: Uhm, sure? I obviously know what *that* means lol; I was referring to the explicit form...

Comment: I added a line where I plugged the result of the integration back into the expression of $A_x$, $A_y$, and $A_z$ obtained above...

Comment: Oh lol, I misunderstood part of your answer, sorry for being stupid. I think my mistake was when squaring integrate the function, I didn't square it; thanks.