# How to find a vector field which "curls" to another?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A vector field $\mathbf{F}$ is called solenoidal if $\mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{F}=0$, and this is an equivalent condition to the existance of some vector field $\mathbf{A}$ such that $\mathbf{\nabla} \times \mathbf{A}=\mathbf{F}$. Why is this true? How would we go about finding $\mathbf{A}$?

Comment: See this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129104/how-to-find-a-vector-potential-inverse-curl?rq=1

Comment: And this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81405/anti-curl-operator

Comment: And also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_potential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's true that $\nabla \cdot \left(\nabla \times \mathbf{A} \right) = 0$, for any vector field $\mathbf{A}$, only *under the correct assumptions* does $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} = 0$ imply that there exists a vector field $\mathbf{A}$ such that $\nabla \times \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{F}$.

If $\mathbf{F}$ is defined on a **contractible** subset of $\Bbb{R}^3$ (in particular, all of $\Bbb{R}^3$ works), then one can find a vector potential $\mathbf{A}$.  (This is the essence of the [Poincaré Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Poincar.C3.A9_lemma) for differential forms.  In fact, the failure for some solenoidal vector fields to have any vector potential is the starting point of de Rham cohomology and algebraic topology.)

For instance, the field $\mathbf{F}$ defined on $\Bbb{R}^3 \setminus \{ \mathbf{0} \}$ by
$$
\mathbf{F}(x, y, z) = \left( \frac{x}{r^3}, \frac{y}{r^3}, \frac{z}{r^3} \right),
$$
where $r^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ is solenoidal, but has no vector potential.