# Is a curl-free vector field always a gradient?

Tags: differential-topology, vector-analysis, hodge-theory

I tried to prove this problem using the Helmholtz decomposition theorem, but it seems the two are entirely contradictory--thus leaving me with empty hands. Does anyone know how to proceed?

[image: problem]

Thanks

Moehringer

Comment: it is locally, but you are asked about cohomology. Anyway, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81405/anti-curl-operator

Comment: @moehringer : I don't know anything about the Helmholtz decomposition theorem, but how far did you get?  Did you do (a) and (b)?  How far did you get on (c) and (d)?

Comment: I see, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition which says nothing more here than the Poincare Lemma, that is there is a solution in a small disk around any point, or ball in three dimensions.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology

Comment: Saying that $F$ is a vector field "in the plane" is a bit misleading. It is, as noted in (c), a vector field on the punctured plane. On a simply connected domain, a curl-free vector field _is_ a gradient.

Comment: The curl of your vector field F is the Dirac delta measure on the origin, i.e. it's everywhere zero except at the origin, and it integrates to 1.

Answer (score -1):

Read an answer here:      **Helmholtz decomposition contradictions** PDF http://analysis3.com/Helmholtz-decomposition-contradictions-pdf-e117376.html

Comment: Please avoid posting links only answers.

Answer (score -1):

Read an answer here: Helmholtz decomposition contradictions PDF
https://www.academia.edu/34072970/Helmholtz_Decomposition_Remains_Opened_for_Future_Researchers

Comment: Nice thesis! This link has been useful to me.