# How to determine if a vector field is the curl of another vector field?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

I want to see if the Stokes theorem can be applied to a given flux integral of the vector field $F$.  To do so, I need to determine if the vector field $F$ is the curl of some other vector field.  How would I determine this?

Comment: Check its divergence? A divergence-free field is the curl of another field.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense Cameron.  If div F = 0, F is the curl of another field, Stokes theorem applies.  See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: However it does not give you the explicit expression of the field, which you need for the Stokes theorem.

Comment: No, I suppose it doesn't.  Actually finding which vector field G F is the curl of might require some integration.

Comment: As it happens, I answered a question on how to invert the curl operator fairly recently, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1556442/221811).

Comment: Look at the wiki page of [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition), it tell you how to decompose a vector field into a curl-free and divergence-free components. For a vector field to be curl of something, it need to be divergence-free and the wiki page also have the formula for building the corresponding vector potentials.

Comment: Contra @Cameron Williams, a divergence-free field (in three dimensions, say) is **not** necessarily the curl of another field. That implication holds only if the field is defined in a region with vanishing second cohomology.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: In Newtonian mechanics the gravitational field of a point mass is divergence free but is not the curl of any vector field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine whether a vector field can be written as the curl of another vector field (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) by looking at it's divergence.  Assume a vector field $F$ can be written as the curl of another vector field, call it $G$.  Then $F = \text{curl}~G$.  Take the divergence of $F$, and say $\text{div}~F \not= 0$.  Then, as implied by Clairaut's Theorem, $\text{div}~F = \text{div}(\text{curl}~G) = 0$, which contradicts $\text{div}~F \not= 0$.  So therefore $F$ is not the curl of another vector field if $\text{div}~F \not= 0$.  So if $\text{div}~F = 0$, then the field is the curl of another field.  It also means the vector field is incompressible (solenoidal)!

S/O to Cameron Williams for making me realize the connection to divergence there.

Comment: Note that this does require that the domain is simply connected, else cohomology comes and bites you.

Comment: ^Right! In my multivariate calculus we typically only deal with simply connected domains, but yeah, always check for that, also when deciding on properties of conservation based solely on the curl.

Comment: See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to typeset math on this site using mathjax/latex. It's really easy to learn.

Comment: Okay, new to StackExchange, thanks Winther!

Comment: Your argument only shows that if $F$ is the curl of $G$ **then** $\text{div}~F = 0$. It does not show that if $\text{div}~F = 0$ **then** $F = \text{curl}~G$ which is what you want. [See this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) for this.

Comment: @Chappers: you mean contractible, not simply connected. The obstruction to a solenoidal field (in three dimensions) having a vector potential deals with second cohomology, not first cohomology. I see this error (saying "simply connected" where "contractible" or "vanishing $k$-th cohomology" for $k\neq1$ is meant) all the time on the internet. A nice counterexample of a solenoidal (divergence-free) field that is not the curl of another field even in a simply connected domain is given on page 126 of *Counterexamples in Analysis*.

Comment: @symplectomorphic You're right, of course. And thank you for the reference, which I shall no doubt end up waving at undergraduates!

Comment: This answer is wrong. The vector field $G(x) = |x|^{-3}x$ is divergence free but is not the curl of any vector field. The answer is right if it is made very clear that the divergence free vector field is defined on *all of $R^{3}$*.

Comment: As others have said, this answer is wrong. Even following the original argument, this line doesn't follow at all from what comes before it: "So if div F=0, then the field is the curl of another field." This shouldn't be accepted as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I found an algorithm that seems to work out, but perhaps someone can advise me where the divergence free comes into-play to power this algorithm.

Let $\textbf F$ be a Euclidean vector-field such that $\nabla \cdot \textbf{F}=0$. If there exists a vector-field $\textbf A$ such that $F=\nabla \times A,$ then we have the following set of equations. Additionally, I have found that they have the corresponding solutions, where $\oplus $ is the exclusive or symbol:
$$\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial A_y}{\partial z}=F_x: A_z=\int F_x dy \oplus A_y=-\int F_x dz $$

$$-\left(\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial z}\right)=F_y: A_z=-\int F_ydx \oplus A_x=\int F_y dz$$

$$\frac{\partial A_y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial y}=F_z: A_y=\int F_zdx \oplus A_x=-\int F_zdy$$

These exclusive or $\oplus $ solutions yield two choices for $\textbf A$