# Find vector field when you know the curl $\nabla \times \mathbf{H}=\mathbf{J}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, vector-fields, curl

This is a problem that arose in my electromagnetics class, but it is purely maths.

**Problem**

> We have the current density vector defined in two different areas (in cylindrical coordinates) $$\mathbf{J}=\mathbf{a_r}\cdot(\sigma_1\cdot \rho \cdot \frac{a}{r\varepsilon_1}) \: \: \: \: \text{for} \: a<r<c$$
> $$\mathbf{J}=\mathbf{a_r}\cdot(\sigma_2\cdot \rho \cdot \frac{a}{r\varepsilon_2}) \: \: \: \: \text{for} \: c<r<b $$
> Where $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\rho,a,\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2$ are just constants, and $\mathbf{a_r}$ is a unit vector.
>
> There is the following relationship between the magnetic field $\mathbf{H}$, and the current density $\mathbf{J}$: $$\nabla \times \mathbf{H}=\mathbf{J} $$
> It is also known that $$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{J}=0 $$
>
> Find $\mathbf{H}$ for both cases of $\mathbf{J}$.

**My attempt**

The curl of a vector field $A$ in cylindrical coordinates can be found using this "formula".
$$\nabla\times A=\mathbf{a_r}\cdot\bigg(\frac{\partial A_z}{r\partial\phi}-\frac{\partial A_{\phi}}{\partial z}\bigg)+\mathbf{a_{\phi}}\cdot \bigg(\frac{\partial A_r}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial r} \bigg) +\mathbf{a_z} \cdot \frac{1}{r}\bigg[\frac{\partial (rA_{\phi})}{\partial r}-\frac{\partial A_r}{\partial \phi}\bigg] $$

In our case, $\mathbf{J}$ only has an $\mathbf{a_r}$ component, so we end up with these three equations.
$$\frac{\partial H_z}{r\partial\phi}-\frac{\partial H_{\phi}}{\partial z} =\sigma_1\rho_1 \cdot\frac{a}{r\varepsilon_1}$$
$$\frac{\partial H_r}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial H_z}{\partial r}=0 $$
$$\frac{\partial (rH_{\phi})}{\partial r}-\frac{\partial H_r}{\partial \phi}=0 $$

And here I have some difficulties, because I don't know how to solve these equations.  $A$ is a vector field, and not just a regular set of variables.

I don't even know if this is the intended way to solve the problem, or if I'm supposed to use some other methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find vector field given curl](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915290/find-vector-field-given-curl)

Comment: No. I wouldn't know how to answer my problem with that link you provided. @Winther