# How to prove the existence of a vector potential for a solenoidal vector field?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If $\textbf{F}$ is a vector field and $\bf{divF}=0$, how would you show that this implies the existence of a vector field $\bf{A}$ such that $\bf{F}=curl A $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the de Rham cohomology group of $\mathbb{R}^3$ being trivial in the second dimension (i.e., every vector field with divergence zero is the curl of another vector field).  What is special about $\mathbb{R}^3$ which allows this is that it is contractible to a point, so there are no obstructions to there being such a vector field.  (It's also true that every vector field with curl zero is the gradient of some continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^3$ as well.)

The answer [Anti-curl operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81405/anti-curl-operator) gives a way of finding the vector field (and since there is a way to find it, this *is* the existence proof).

Answer (score 2):

If the domain is star-shaped,
$${\mathbf A}({\mathbf x})=\int_0^1{\mathbf F}(t{\mathbf x})\times t{\mathbf x}\,dt.$$
See [Vector Potentials](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~houghton/231/Notes/ChrisFord/vp.pdf).

Comment: Do you have any intuition for this formula? How could one come up with it?