# $N$-dimensional Anti-Curl Operator

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, curl

I came across one very interesting, but old topic [Anti-curl operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81405/anti-curl-operator). I do not know the completeness of the solution of this problem, but I was interested in some aspect of it: is it possible to create an anti-curl operator for a vector field of arbitrary dimension?

I'll make a short note. Let's say we have an equation with $\text{Curl}$:

$\nabla\times\textbf{F}=\textbf{V}$

$\textbf{V}$ is known, and need to find $\textbf{F}$.

In practice, special cases of $\text{Curl}$ for 2- and 3-dimensional vector fields are common. In both cases, a system of partial differential equations is compiled, the structure of which shows that $\textbf{F}$ is far from unique. Therefore, arbitrary boundary/initial conditions are used.

$\text{Curl}$ of a vector field with dimension $N>3$ is a tensor, and the system of equations compiled on its basis will obviously be strongly overdetermined.

**Question:** Will the formulas from the [Helmholtz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) work for $N$-dimensional vector fields? Are there any developments on the issue under consideration? Are there any nuances associated with formula for high dimensions?

### Remark:

---

*In the structure of the tensor, after $\text{Curl}$ is applied to a vector field $\textbf{F}$, there are (I don't know what to call them correctly) "symmetric" pairs of equations. This can help in solving a reduced-dimensional PDE system. Below - example for 4-dimensional vector field $\textbf{F}$. Circles mark symmetric pairs of equations.*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\dd{\mathrm d}
$

I think what you're looking for is given by [geometric calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_calculus). This is essentially calculus done over the Clifford algebra associated to the standard inner product of $\R^N$. We can formulate your "$N$-dimensional curl" as $\nabla\wedge F$ for $F$ a vector field, and together with the divergence-free condition $\nabla\cdot F = 0$ the turn into *one* equation
$$
  \nabla F = \nabla\cdot F + \nabla\wedge F = 0 + V = V
$$
where $\nabla\wedge F = V$ is what's called a *bivector*. The LHS is the *geometric* or *Clifford product* of $\nabla$ with $F$. This is advantageous because the operator $F \mapsto \nabla F$ has a Green's function; we can directly solve to get
$$
  F(x)
    = \frac1{S_N}\int_{\partial R}|\dd^{N-1}x'|\,\frac{x'-x}{|x'-x|^N}\hat n(x')F(x')
      - \frac1{S_N}\int_R|\dd^Nx'|\,\frac{x'-x}{|x'-x|^N}V(x')
$$
where $R$ is some region of space with non-zero volume containing $x$, $|\dd^{N-1}x'|$ is the surface area measure on the boundary $\partial R$, $|dd^Nx'|$ is the volume measure on $R$, $S_N$ is the surface area of a unit $N$-ball (i.e. the $(N-1)$-volume of an $(N-1)$-sphere), $n(x')$ is the outward-pointing unit normal to $\partial R$ at $x'$, and $x'$ is the variable of integration. The first term is a boundary term, and requires specifying boundary conditions on $F$.

The above formula is (apart from some differences in notation) equation 4.16 of section 7-4 in *Clifford Algebra to Geometric Calculus* (1984) by David Hestenes and Garret Sobczyk. I will warn you that this book is difficult to read. I would instead recommend *Geometric Algebra for Physicists* (2003) by Chris Doran and Anthony Lasenby as an introduction [geometric algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra) (a particular way of thinking about Clifford algebras) and geometric calculus, though I believe the above equation is stated only for the (important) case $\nabla F = 0$ (i.e. zero divergence and zero curl).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and links to literature! I would check with interest the formula that is proposed here, but I do not know how to calculate such integrals. Could you show how this is done in Mathematica for example for `V = {x, -y, z}`

Comment: @dtn I don't know Mathematica. All you need is a way to do the Clifford products, and then the integrals are just the usual volume and surface integrals. A quick search gave me [this package](https://github.com/jlaragonvera/Geometric-Algebra). Alternatively, the first integrand is a product of three vectors $XnF$; since the result has to be a vector this can be expanded as $$ (X\cdot n)F + (n\cdot F)X - (X\cdot F)n. $$ If the bivector $V = v_1\wedge v_2$ for vectors $v_1, v_2$ then the second integrand $XV$ can be expanded as $$ (X\cdot v_1)v_2 - (X\cdot v_2)v_1. $$ (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) In this case $V$ can be thought of as representing the plane spanned by $v_1, v_2$; however, not all bivectors are of this form.