# How to solve $f_1,f_2,f_3$ from the simultaneous PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

How to solve $f_1,f_2,f_3$ from the following simultaneous PDEs:

$\frac{\partial f_3(x,y)}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial f_2(z,x)}{\partial z}=y^2,$

$\frac{\partial f_1(y,z)}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial f_3(x,y)}{\partial x}=z^2,$

$\frac{\partial f_2(z,x)}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial f_1(y,z)}{\partial y}=x^2.$

Attempt:

I can intutively say that $f_1(y,z)=\frac{z^3}{3}$, $f_2(z,x)=\frac{x^3}{3}$ and $f_3(x,y)=\frac{y^3}{3}$ satisfy the above equations.

But how to say it in a generalized way?

Comment: You only found the particular solution, but not the homogeneous:
$$f_{1}\! \left(y,z\right) = \frac{z^{3}}{3}+\left(c_{1} y+c_{3}\right) z+c_{2} y+c_{4},
\\
f_{2}\! \left(x,z\right) = \frac{x^{3}}{3}+\left(c_{1} z+c_{2}\right) x+c_{5} z+c_{7},
\\
f_{3}\! \left(x,y\right) = \frac{y^{3}}{3}+\left(c_{1} x+c_{5}\right) y+c_{3} x+c_{6}$$

Comment: @gpmath Ok..How to get this particular solution, please elaborate

Comment: Please write in "Answer Your Question" style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's examine the first PDE,
$$
\frac{\partial f_3(x,y)}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial f_2(z,x)}{\partial z}=y^2. \tag{1}
$$
Since $f_2$ does not depend on $y$, if we differentiate both sides of $(1)$ with respect to $y$ we obtain
$$
\frac{\partial^2f_3(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=2y. \tag{2}
$$
Integrating the above equation twice, we obtain
$$
f_3(x,y)=\frac{y^3}{3}+g_3(x)y+h_3(x), \tag{3}
$$
where $g_3$ and $h_3$ are, for the moment, arbitrary functions of $x$. A similar reasoning with the other two PDEs shows that
\begin{align}
f_1(y,z)&=\frac{z^3}{3}+g_1(y)z+h_1(y), \tag{4} \\
f_2(z,x)&=\frac{x^3}{3}+g_2(z)x+h_2(z). \tag{5}
\end{align}
Now, let's return to the first PDE. Substituting $(3)$ and $(5)$ in $(1)$, we obtain
$$
g_3(x)-g_2'(z)x-h_2'(z)=0. \tag{6}
$$
Differentiating both sides of $(6)$ with respect to $x$ yields
$g_3'(x)-g_2'(z)=0$. Since $g_3'$ is a function of $x$ and $g_2'$ is a function of $z$, this identity can only be true if $g_3'(x)=g_2'(z)=A$, where $A$ is a constant. Therefore,
\begin{align}
g_3(x)&=Ax+B, \tag{7} \\
g_2(z)&=Az+C. \tag{8}
\end{align}
Substituting $(7)$ and $(8)$ in $(6)$, we obtain $B-h_2'(z)=0$, from which follows
$$
h_2(z)=Bz+D. \tag{9}
$$
Repeating this procedure with the other two PDEs, one obtains $g_1(y)$, $h_1(y)$, and $h_3(x)$. This is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are looking for a field $F$ such that $$\nabla \times F=(y^2, z^2, x^2), $$ check this [Anti-curl operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81405/anti-curl-operator)

Comment: Is there any method to solve other that Anti-curl operator?